# Complex stdout check in Ansible

Tags: output, stdout, ansible

I run a job on a remote server with Ansible. The stdout generates some output where sometimes errors show up. The error text is in the form of

`#ERROR FMM0129E The following error was returned by the vSphere(TM) API: 'Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password.'.`

The thing is that some of these errors can safely be ignored and only these that are not in my false positive list should raise a fail.

My question is, can this be done in a pure Ansible way?

The only thing that comes to mind is the simple failed_when check which, in this case, falls short. I am thinking that these "complex" output checking should be done out of Ansible, invoking a python / shell / etc. script to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are remotely executing a shell command anyway then there's no reason why you couldn't wrap that in a shell script that returns a non 0 status code for the things you care about and then simply execute that via the [`script`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) module.

#### example.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

randomInt=$[ 1 + $[ RANDOM % 10 ]]

echo $randomInt

if [ $randomInt == 1 ]; then
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

And then use it like this in your playbook:

```
- name: run example.sh
  script: example.sh
```

Ansible will automatically see any non 0 return codes as the task failing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `failed_when` you could use `ignore_errors: true` which would get you into the position of passing the failing task and forwarding the stdout to another task. But I would not recommend this, since in my opinion a task should never ever report a failed state by intend. But if you feel this is an option for you, there even would be a way to reset the error counter so the Ansible stats at the end are correct.

```
- some: task
  register: some_result
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Reset errors after intentional fail
  meta: clear_host_errors
  when: some_result | failed

- another: task
    check: "{{ some_result.stdout }}
  when: some_result | failed
```

The last task then would check your stdout in a custom script or whatever you have and should report a failed state itself (return code != 0).

As far as I know the `clear_host_errors` feature is yet undocumented and the [commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/da9ae14ff6ca488a5cca1d68171eb0ad5c747c8d) is about a month old, so I guess it will only be available in Ansible 2.0.1.

---

Another idea would be to wrap your task *inside* the script which checks the output or pipe it to that script. That obviously will only work if you run a shell command and not with any other ansible modules.

Other than those two options I don't think there is anything else available.